# regex split to multi matches

Tags: php, regex

How can I split the different links.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/page/?link1=2&page=2#fff">pag2 </a></li><li><a href="/page/">pag2 </a></li><li><a href="/page/">pag2 </a></li>
</ul>
```

I try something like that, but it didn't find it at all

```
$re = '/<a href=["\'](([^\'\"\#]*)?)(?=[\'"\#])(.*)["\']>[^<\/a>]+<\/a>/mi';
$str = '<ul>
<li><a href="/page/">pag2 </a></li><li><a href="/page/">pag2 </a></li><li><a href="/page/">pag2 </a></li>
</ul>


';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Also try this, but it capture it all

```
$re = '/<a href=["\'](([^\'\"\#]*)?)(?=[\'"\#])(.*)["\']>.+<\/a>/mi';
```

Comment: Do you know that you don't need RegExes for this and shouldn't go with them?

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - use a parser

Comment: @ctwheels - He's stripping out links from a string. The identifier is the `href`. You don't need to parse it here, you just need to globally find `href` and capture it's contents.

You don't even need to look at the surrounding tags.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252390/the-famous-tag-regex-answer-should-its-title-be-edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\shref=(["'])(.*?)\1
```

Breakdown:

- `\s` - a space character, as not to match `<other-prefix>-href="example.com"`
- `href=` - match `href=` literally
- `(["'])` - capture the type of quote used (group 1)
- `(.*?)` capture everything until (group 2)
- `\1` - you find the type of quote used (matches what was matched in group 1)

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nf11zj/1)

Comment: can It work if like life href="pgae/?p=1&b=2#33" ?

Comment: Absolutely: https://regex101.com/r/nf11zj/3

Comment: @boaz It will match any references to `href` in the format `href="example.com"`, whether in text or out of text. But should be what you need.

Comment: Tanks. Can the #33 be in another group?

Comment: @boaz Try this: `\shref=(["'])(.*?)(#.*?)?\1` - https://regex101.com/r/nf11zj/5 . It will put the `#33` (or `#fff`) in another group, if one exists